# Autocomplete google maps JS error

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have been trying to get the autocomplete to work with class name although since I have done that I cannot add the event listener anymore ? Anyone has got a solution to that ?

This is my code

```
function InitiliazeGoogleSearch() {
 var input = document.getElementsByClassName('js-autocomplete');
 for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input[i]);
 }

 google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
    if(!$('.js-main-filter_wrapper').css('display','block')) {
        $('.js-main-filter_wrapper').slideToggle();
    }
 });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your loop you are re-assigning the `autocomplete` variable, but you are only attaching the listener to the last one, since it's outside the loop. To have a listener for each, you need it in the loop.

```
function InitiliazeGoogleSearch() {
    var input = document.getElementsByClassName('js-autocomplete');
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input[i]);

        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
            if (!$('.js-main-filter_wrapper').css('display', 'block')) {
                $('.js-main-filter_wrapper').slideToggle();
            }
        });
    }
}
```